# Android Contact Picker Intent always return empty extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, android-bundle

I have got a contact picking method that uses two extras to specify whether you are creating a new contact shortcut in my app or editing an existing one.

Problem is that no matter what I do, the extras always seem to be null, causing a nullPointerException when I try to access them.

I suspect that setting the intent type to `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE` resets any user-defined extras, but I am not sure.

Here is what I am doing at the moment:

**Contact Picking Intent**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putBoolean("isEditing", isEditing);
                extras.putLong("shortcut", shortcut.getId());
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

And in **onActivityResult()**

```
switch (requestCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST):
                if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                    Boolean isEditing = false;
                    long shortcutId = 0;
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bundle Not Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (bundle.containsKey("isEditing")) {
                            isEditing = bundle.getBoolean("isEditing", false);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + isEditing, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        if (bundle.containsKey("shortcutId")) {
                            shortcutId = bundle.getLong("shortcutId", 0);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + shortcutId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
```

The toasts are never shown because the bundle is not found I guess. 
I have tried a different workflow too, using `Intent.putExtraString("isEditing", value)` and then getting them with `intent.getStringExtra("isEditing", false)` skipping packing the extras in a bundle (haven't quite understood the difference between the two workflows) but alas, I faced the same problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Edit:
When you put your `long` value, you do

```
extras.putLong("shortcut", shortcut.getId());
```

So you have to retrieve it like

```
long shortcutId = bundle.getLong("shortcut", 0);
```

Then you have to get the `Bundle` extras from the `Intent` that launched the `Activity`, like below.

```
switch (requestCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST):
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            //Here you get the intent extras
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            //Boolean isEditing = false;
            //long shortcutId = 0;
            if (bundle != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bundle Not Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (bundle.hasExtras()){
                    boolean isEditing = bundle.getBoolean("isEditing", false);                            
                    long shortcutId = bundle.getLong("shortcut", 0);
                    if(isEditiong != null)
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + isEditing, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(shortcutId != null)
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + shortcutId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }            
    }
    break;
}
```